# text with different reflection

Tags: tikz-pgf, reflection

Καλημέρα!

I 'm want to have a word (Παρατηρήσεις) like a reflection below of a math text. I want:

- each letter to be bellow of each symbol,
- all the math text in the same line,
- all the image could be rotated.

I tried this, but as you can see the reflections are not good.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}

\newcommand{\iu}{{i\mkern1mu}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\mytext{$\prod\limits_{j=1}^{9} \overrightarrow{\alpha} \rho_1 \mathbb{A} T_{3}H_0 \dfrac{\varrho}{2} \eta' \sum\limits_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \exists \iu \int_{0}^{1}$}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={anchor=south,inner sep=0}}
\node[mynode]{\mytext};
\node[scope fading=south,opacity=0.4,yscale=-1,mynode]{Παρατηρήσεις};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{turn}{180}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90]
\def\mytext{$\prod\limits_{j=1}^{9} \overrightarrow{\alpha} \rho_1 \mathbb{A} T_{3}H_0 \dfrac{\varrho}{2} \eta' \sum\limits_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \exists \iu \int_{0}^{1}$}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={anchor=south,inner sep=0}}
\node[mynode]{\mytext};
\node[scope fading=south,opacity=0.4,yscale=-1,mynode]{Παρατηρήσεις};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{turn}

\end{document}
```

I also tried this, but the lines are not good.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}

\newcommand{\iu}{{i\mkern1mu}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\mytext{$\prod\limits_{j=1}^{9} $}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={anchor=south,inner sep=0}}
\node[mynode]{\mytext};
\node[scope fading=south,opacity=0.4,yscale=-1,mynode]{Π};
\end{tikzpicture}
%  no empty line here 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\mytext{$\overrightarrow{\alpha} $}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={anchor=south,inner sep=0}}
\node[mynode]{\mytext};
\node[scope fading=south,opacity=0.4,yscale=-1,mynode]{α};
\end{tikzpicture}
%  no empty line here 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\mytext{$ \rho_1 $}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={anchor=south,inner sep=0}}
\node[mynode]{\mytext};
\node[scope fading=south,opacity=0.4,yscale=-1,mynode]{ρ};
\end{tikzpicture}
%  no empty line here 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\mytext{$\mathbb{A}$}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={anchor=south,inner sep=0}}
\node[mynode]{\mytext};
\node[scope fading=south,opacity=0.4,yscale=-1,mynode]{α};
\end{tikzpicture}... ...

\end{document}
```

Is any solution?

Ευχαριστώ εκ των προτέρων!

Comment: (I have studied so much math that I can read the greek in-betweens) Kalimera! Do you want to mirror the letters individually like bd/pq or rotate the whole text?

Comment: When you are saying "each letter to be below of each symbol", what precisely is a symbol? Is `\rho_1` one symbol or two? Likewise is `\prod\limits_{j=1}^{9}` one symbol or many?

Comment: \prod\limits_{j=1}^{9} = Π *** \overrightarrow{\alpha} = α *** \rho_1 = ρ *** \mathbb{A} = α *** T_{3} = Τ *** H_0 = η *** \dfrac{\varrho}{2} = ρ *** \eta' = ή *** \sum\limits_{j\in\mathbb{N}} = σ *** \exists = ε *** \iu =ι *** \int_{0}^{1} = ς

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not yet be the answer you are hoping for, but perhaps a first step towards such an answer. First of all, my editor does not deal with the Greek letters. So I produced them in the LaTeX way. (Of course, I could switch to another editor, but this would mean to exclude everyone whose editor has the same problem from being able to copy this answer, something I do not want to do.) Then I guess one has to decompose the formula into atoms. (I do not know if one can do that with `decorations.text`.) And then a loop over the atoms allows one to attach the mirrors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\newcommand{\iu}{{i\mkern1mu}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit,fadings}
\def\lstMirrors{{"\Pi","\alpha","\rho","\alpha","\eta","\rho","\eta","\sigma","\varepsilon","\iota","\zeta","\zeta"}}
    \begin{document}
\[\tikzmarknode{1}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{9}} 
\tikzmarknode{2}{\overrightarrow{\alpha}} 
\tikzmarknode{3}{\rho_1} 
\tikzmarknode{4}{\mathbb{A}} 
\tikzmarknode{5}{T_{3}}
\tikzmarknode{6}{H_0}
\tikzmarknode{7}{\dfrac{\varrho}{2}} 
\tikzmarknode{8}{\eta'} 
\tikzmarknode{9}{\sum\limits_{j\in\mathbb{N}}} 
\tikzmarknode{10}{\exists} 
\tikzmarknode{11}{\iu} 
\tikzmarknode{12}{\int_{0}^{1}}\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\foreach \X in {1,...,12}
{\ifnum\X=1
\xdef\lstFit{(\X)}
\else
\xdef\lstFit{\lstFit(\X)}
\fi}
\node[fit=\lstFit](fit){};
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X-1)}]in {1,...,12}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{\lstMirrors[\Y]}
\node[scope fading=south,opacity=0.4,yscale=-1,anchor=south] at 
(\X.south |- fit.south) {\ensuremath{\tmp}}; }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can one rotate this? Yes, e.g. by packing it into a `\savebox`. I hesitate to put too much effort in this preliminary answer because you may find it unacceptable to use an editor that cannot deal with Greek characters. However, if you are OK with that and give me further feedback on the features you want to have, I will be happy to expand this answer.

Comment: Thank's a lot!!! That's all I wanted! I only fix the 5th letter witch is "τ", and the final, witch is "ς".